# PHP socket pack data

Tags: php, sockets, imap, pack

```
<?php

$desthost = "imap.gmail.com";
$port     = 993;
$conflag  = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT;

try
{
    $socket = stream_socket_client( "tcp://host:port", $errno, $errstr, 15, $conflag );

    fwrite( $socket, pack( "C3", 0x05, 0x01, 0x00 ) );
    $server_status = fread( $socket, 2048 );
    if ( $server_status == pack( "C2", 0x05, 0x00 ) )
    {
        // Connection succeeded
    }
    else
    {
        die( "SOCKS Server does not support this version and/or authentication method of SOCKS.\r\n" );
    }

    fwrite( $socket, pack( "C5", 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, strlen( $desthost ) ) . $desthost . pack( "n", $port ) );
    $server_buffer = fread( $socket, 10 );

    var_dump(unpack("C5", $server_buffer));


    if ( ord( $server_buffer[0] ) == 5 && ord( $server_buffer[1] ) == 0 && ord( $server_buffer[2] ) == 0 )
    {
        // Connection succeeded
    }
    else
    {
        die( "The SOCKS server failed to connect to the specificed host and port. ( " . $desthost . ":" . $port . " )\r\n" );
    }

    stream_socket_enable_crypto( $socket, TRUE, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT );
}
catch ( Exception $e )
{
    die( $e->getMessage() );
}

if ( $socket === FALSE )
{
    die( "bad socket" );
}

//fwrite( $socket, "GET /\n" );
echo fread( $socket, 8192 );
```

This code connect to proxy and connect to imap via proxy. I can't understand how this pack works ?

what does mean fwrite( $socket, pack( "C3", 0x05, 0x01, 0x00 ) ); ?

and what does mean next code ?

```
fwrite( $socket, pack( "C5", 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, strlen( $desthost ) ) . $desthost . pack( "n", $port ) );
```

I think it's "CONNECT host:port" ? Can somebody please explain me about that ? When I try to send command "0000001 LOGIN login pass" imap returns me error bad syntax. Seems I should pack this command or something like this.

Comment: It is simply saying, send the three bytes 5, 1, and 0, then the five bytes, 5, 1, 0, 3, [lengthof host].  It is  binary protocol, there's no 'CONNECT' word anywhere. (Connect is used by HTTP proxies, not SOCKS proxies)

Comment: thank you! But what does those bytes say for proxy ? And how can I make authorization if proxy protected with password ?

Comment: There is an overview here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS , and SOCKS5 is formally specified in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overview of the SOCKS protocol at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS.

This is some dirty code to quickly connect to a SOCKS proxy.

`fwrite( $socket, pack( "C3", 0x05, 0x01, 0x00 ) );` means sends the bytes 5, 1, and 0.

In an initial connection request this means "SOCKS version `5`", `1` authentication method supported, and that one authentication method is `No authentication`.

`if ( $server_status == pack( "C2", 0x05, 0x00 ) )` is checking that the server responded with "Socks version `5`, Use `No Authentication`".

`fwrite( $socket, pack( "C5", 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, strlen( $desthost ) ) . $desthost . pack( "n", $port ) );` is sending a connection request:

- 5 (SOCKS version 5)
- 1 (TCP connection request)
- 0 (Reserved)
- 3 (Use a domain name)
- `length` of domain name
- The domain name
- port number in network byte order

`if ( ord( $server_buffer[0] ) == 5 && ord( $server_buffer[1] ) == 0 && ord( $server_buffer[2] ) == 0 )` is checking the server response.

- 5 Socks version 5
- 0 Request granted
- 0 Reserved byte.

There are more fields but it's ignoring them, and hoping that they fit exactly into 10 bytes, which may not be true if it returns back the domain address or an IPv6 address.

At this point, the connection to the remote server is established.  It then upgrades it to TLS, and should otherwise work as expected.

For your IMAP commands after this point, make sure they end in "\r\n".  You don't actually show your code for this, so we can't help debug it.

SOCKS5 is formally specified in [RFC1928](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928).

Comment: Thank you a lot!! Let me ask, what means "\r\n" ?

Comment: Every command you send to an IMAP server must end with the string "\r\n", such as `001 LOGIN user password\r\n`.  This is a Carriage Return/New Line combination.